# How to use docker volumes in Concourse pipeline

Tags: docker, concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-task

Below is my pipeline

```
---
resource_types:
- name: pull-request
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: teliaoss/github-pr-resource

resources:
- name: pull-request
  type: pull-request
  check_every: 5m
  # webhook_token: ((webhook-token))
  source:
    repository: engx/engx-intuitive
    base_branch: concourse
    access_token: ((github-access-token))
    v3_endpoint: https://github.com/api/v3
    v4_endpoint: https://github.com/api/graphql

jobs:
- name: intuitive
  plan:
  - get: pull-request
    trigger: true
    version: every
  - put: pull-request
    params:
      path: pull-request
      status: pending
  - task: build engx-intuitive
    params:
      GOPROXY: "https://proxy.golang.org"
      CGO_ENABLED: "0"
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: registry-image
        source:
          repository: docker
          tag: latest
          volumes: /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      inputs:
```

it fails with below error if I use `volumes`

```
resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1

stderr:
[31mERRO[0m[0000] invalid payload: json: unknown field "volumes"
```

if not, below failure is seen

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```